# Django: How to stop giving new user Staff status and Superuser status status in default

Tags: python, django

When I register a new user, I can log in with my superuser account on the admin page. The error is that "Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive".

I found out that the new user has permissions on Staff status and Superuser status in default. And I can log in admin page in the new user account. So, I thought the login error happens because of giving the new user Staff and Superuser permissions in default.

I thought these codes

`password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))`
`password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Repeat your password'}))` in forms.py are the reason. So I tried register both with them and not with them. But, the result was same.

1. How to make the new user has only active status permissions, not the Staff and Superuser permissions in default?
2. Is my assumption for the admin login error right?
   2-1) If not, how to solve this?

This is **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from .forms import SignUpForm, ProfileForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
  
from .models import *
from django.contrib import messages


from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def update_profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)

        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            
            user = form.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            
            profile.save()
            # username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            # password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            # user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    
    context = {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form}
    return render(request, 'common/register.html', context)
```

This is **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from apps.userprofile.models import Profile

# from django.db.models import fields

# from django.db import models
# from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your first name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your last name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=False, help_text='Enter a valid email address', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Repeat your password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'})
        }
        fields = [
            'username', 
            'first_name', 
            'last_name', 
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2', 
        ]

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields= [ 'student_ID', 'CBNU_PW' ]
        widgets = {
            'student_ID': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'student_ID'}),
            'CBNU_PW': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'CBNU_PW'})
        }
```

This is **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    CBNU_PW = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: Please clarify, because you've given some conflicting informations. What is the value of `staff` and `superuser` fields after you've registered a new user through your views? What is value of those fields when you're receiving the error message trying to log in to the admin panel?

Comment: @GwynBliedD                                                                                                                    
 1) new user that I register gets `staff` and `superuser` permissions.                                 
 But, I didn't set the user to have the  `staff` and `superuser` permissions. I want the user don't have these permissions.

Comment: 2) I can't log in admin page with my superuser id after registration. But, I can log in admin page with new user account

Comment: Both `staff` and `superuser` values should default to False. Do you have a custom user model defined?